# How to pass command line args to program in SBT 0.13.1?

Tags: sbt

I just switched to SBT 0.13.1 and either arg handling changed or there's a bug. Here's what I'm testing with (named `sbt-test.scala`):

```
#!/bin/sh
SBT_0_13_0="/path/to/sbt-launch-0.13.0.jar"
SBT_0_13_1="/path/to/sbt-launch-0.13.1.jar"
SBT="$SBT_0_13_1"
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain -jar "$SBT" $0 "$@"
!#

/***
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.0"
)
*/

import com.typesafe.config.{ConfigFactory, Config}

println(s"Args: ${args mkString ", "}")

val cfg = ConfigFactory.parseString(
  """
    |credentials {
    |  user = someone
    |  pass = s3cr3t
    |}
  """.stripMargin)

println(cfg getString "credentials.user")
```

When I run `./sbt-test.scala --arg=val` I get the following error:

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: arg
[error] arg=val
```

Running the same script with the same argument with SBT 0.13.0 yields the expected:

```
Args: --arg=val
someone
```

Similarly, if I turn that executable script into an actual SBT project and attempt to run `sbt run --flag` I get

```
[error] Not a valid command: flag (similar: iflast, last, alias)
[error] flag
```

Answer (score 18):

See the documentation on [Batch mode](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Running.html#batch-mode):

> ### Batch mode
>
> You can also run sbt in batch mode, specifying a space-separated list of sbt commands as arguments. For sbt commands that take arguments, pass the command and arguments as one argument to `sbt` by enclosing them in quotes. For example,
>
> ```
> $ sbt clean compile "testOnly TestA TestB"
> ```
>
> In this example, `testOnly` has arguments, `TestA` and `TestB`. The commands will be run in sequence (`clean`, `compile`, then `testOnly`).

So if you don't want `--flag` to be interpreted as a command, you have to quote it with run:

```
$ sbt "run --flag"
```

### sbt script runner

The scripting is described in [Scripts, REPL, and Dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Scripts.html), which seems to say you don't need extra quotes other than the bash quotes:

> ```
> java -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain -Dsbt.boot.directory=/home/user/.sbt/boot -jar sbt-launch.jar "$@"
> ```

In reality, to make your script work, you'd need another sets of escaped quotes around `$@` like this:

```
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain -jar "$SBT" $0 "\"$@\""
```

If this is a regression that started in 0.13.1, you should report to sbt.

Comment: what about getting it to run as a script? this is the main focus of the question.

Comment: double quoting only makes it work for a single arg. but if i have something like ./sbt-test.scala --flag --arg=val i get an error on the second arg. i'm going to report it as a bug